# How do I set a the serverResponse var from within the if let data string statement

Tags: swift, var

```
func getResponse(serverName: String) -> String {

        var serverResponse: String = "No Response"
        let serverURL = "http://" + serverName + ":3000"

        if let url = URL(string: serverURL) {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              if let data = data {
                if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                    serverResponse = jsonString
                    print(jsonString)
                 }
               }
           }.resume()
        }
    return serverResponse
}
```

I'm trying to set the `serverResponse` variable from within the if let jsonString but it always returns "No response"(the vars default) and the print function from within the if let jsonString will print out the server response.

Comment: dataTask is asynchronous. your function is returning the value before the server request has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

DataTask is asynchronous. your function is returning the value before the server request has been completed. You should use a completion handler here.

```
func getResponse(serverName: String , completion : @escaping (Bool,String?) -> ()) {

        let serverURL = "http://" + serverName + ":3000"
        if let url = URL(string: serverURL) {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              if let data = data {
                if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print(jsonString)
                    completion(true,jsonString)
                 }
              } else {
                completion(false,nil)
            }
           }.resume()
        }
}
```

Then you can call the above function like this:

```
    getResponse(serverName: "yourServerName") { (isSuccess, response) in
        if isSuccess {
            self.serverResponse = response ?? ""
        } else {
            // your api request failed. show alert or whatever you want to inform the user.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `completionHandler`.

```
func getResponse(serverName: String, onCompletion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

    var serverResponse: String = "No Response"
    let serverURL = "http://" + serverName + ":3000"

    if let url = URL(string: serverURL) {
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
          if let data = data {
            if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {

                serverResponse = jsonString
                print(jsonString)

                onCompletion(serverResponse)
             }
           }
       }.resume()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create `serverResponse` outside the `getResponse(serverName:)` method and use *property observer* **`didSet`** to observe the changes in `serverResponse`, i.e.

```
var serverResponse: String = "No Response" {
    didSet {
        print("newValue: ", serverResponse)
        //add the code here..
    }
}
```

`didSet` will be called every time there is any change in `serverResponse`. So, any code that you want to run after getting the `serverResponse` from API, write here.

Also, no need to return anything from `getResponse(serverName:)` method. So, the method will now look like,

```
func getResponse(serverName: String) {
    let serverURL = "http://" + serverName + ":3000"
    if let url = URL(string: serverURL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    serverResponse = jsonString
                    print(jsonString)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```